# output ImportError libcudart.so.7.5. in window 7 pycharm

Tags: pycharm, tensorflow

**Environment info**

**Operating System:**

tensorflow in Ubuntu 14.04

pycharm in window 7

**Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:**

cuda 7.5 and cudnn v4.0

**If installed from binary pip package, provide:**

**Which pip package you installed.**

tensorflow-0.8-GPU-whl

**The output from python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)".**

0.8

**Steps to reproduce**

1.start samba in ubuntu

2. import remote mnist example by pycharm in window 7
3. change python interpreter to remote ubuntu python
4. run mninst

**What have you tried?**

according to above step , output ImportError libcudart.so.7.5. but ok if run mnist directly by pycharm and command line in ubuntu machine .

**Logs or other output that would be helpful**

ImportError libcudart.so.7.5

Comment: Sorry you're hitting problems! This sounds like you're hitting a bug, so it might get more attention on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues . I also wasn't clear from the description if you're running on Windows, which is not yet a supported platform.